# "it is best" vs. "it is the best"

Tags: articles, definite-article, superlatives

I have met the following expression:

> It is best not to do something.

The issue is I thought that with the superlative form of an adverb we should use the article "the" ("the most" or "the best", e.g.).

Could anybody explain why we can omit "the" here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> This is **the** best **car** in the garage.

We use articles like **the** and **a** before nouns, like **car**. The word "best" is an adjective, and adjectives do not take articles by themselves. Because the noun **car** is modified by the superlative adjective **best**, and because this makes the noun **car** definite in this context, we use **the**.

> It is best not to do something.

Here, we have the adjective **best**, but this adjective is attached to no noun.

The adjective **best** is used in a [copular construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun) with the [dummy pronoun **it**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun). This pronoun does not refer to any object. There's no noun that we can attach **the** to here.

Comment: Took me a while to see how this answer does in fact extend to other examples where "best" is used without "the": the deciding part is if the noun becomes "definite in [the] context", not whether or not there's a real noun.

Comment: @DanGetz -- maybe you could post an additional answer explaining this point.