# Is it always necessary to use definite article before superlative?

Tags: superlatives

Normally we use definite article when we want to talk about something known or specific, but I noticed that always people used to put a definite article before superlatives even when they are talking about something generally.

For example:

> "**The** **best** quality of gold can be found in **the** **most** of the
>   countries".

and I'm wondering what's wrong for example with:

> **Best** quality of gold can be found in **most** of countries

?

Is it always necessary to use definite article before superlatives? No exceptions? If there are examples for not using definite articles when using superlatives I'd like to know about them.

For example, can I say `I am happiest. He is fastest. She is friendliest.` without using definite article?

Comment: None of the two examples are grammatical.

Comment: You might try https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46923/is-there-always-a-the-before-a-superlative-adjective and see if your question is answered there. Note that "most" is not being used as a superlative in your examples. It's instead synonymous with "a majority of."

Comment: related: **1.** [Use of the definite article before superlative adjectives](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/138701/use-of-the-definite-article-before-superlative-adjectives) **2.** [The definite article before superlative degree](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/137014/the-definite-article-before-superlative-degree) **3.** [“it is best” vs. “it is the best”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/77629/it-is-best-vs-it-is-the-best)

Comment: **4.** [“The” before a superlative adjective: why there is no definite article in “Your woodwork was worst of all”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/72774/the-before-a-superlative-adjective-why-there-is-no-definite-article-in-your) **5.** [a most talented writer - why not “the most talented writer”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/39826/a-most-talented-writer-why-not-the-most-talented-writer?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Another question on ELU where you might find useful information: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107741/superlative-and-definite-article-the

Comment: Thank you for the links. Indeed It seems that my question was answered by them. Should I delete the question or leave it for others and vote to close it?

Comment: A better question, inasmuch as the answers are very good: [“love most” versus “love the most”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7038/love-most-versus-love-the-most)

Comment: @subtle_sibling I'm no SE expert, but I think deleting it yourself is preferable.